# Elastic synonym usage in aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, analyzer, synonym

**Situation** :

Elastic version used: 2.3.1

I have an elastic index configured like so

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "british,english",
            "queen,monarch"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is great, when I query the document and use a query term "*english*" or "*queen*" I get all documents matching *british* and *monarch*. When I use a synonym term in filter aggregation it doesnt work. For example

In my index I have 5 documents, 3 of them have monarch, 2 of them have queen

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "status.synonym":{
            "query": "queen",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   },
     "aggs" : {
        "status_terms" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "status.synonym" }
        },
        "monarch_filter" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "status.synonym": "monarch" } }
        }
    },
   "explain" : 0
}
```

The result produces:

Total hits:

- 5 doc count (as expected, great!)
- Status terms: 5 doc count for queen (as expected, great!)
- Monarch filter: 0 doc count

I have tried different synonym filter configuration:

- queen,monarch
- queen,monarch => queen
- queen,monarch => queen,monarch

But the above hasn't changed the results. I was wanting to conclude that maybe you can use filters at query time only but then if terms aggregation is working why shouldn't filter, hence I think its my synonym filter configuration that is wrong. A more extensive synonym filter example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/4095280).

**QUESTION**:

How to use/configure synonyms in filter aggregation?

**Example to replicate the case above**:
1. Create and configure index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "wlh,wellhead=>wellwell"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/_mapping/job
{
  "properties": {
    "title":{
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
    }
  }
}
```

2.Put two documents:

```
PUT my_index/job/1
{
    "title":"wellhead smth else"
}

PUT my_index/job/2
{
    "title":"wlh other stuff"
}
```

3.Execute a search on *wlh* which should return 2 documents; have a terms aggregation which should have 2 documents for *wellwell* and a filter which shouldn't have 0 count:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "title":{
            "query": "wlh",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   },
     "aggs" : {
        "wlhAggs" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "title" }
        },
        "wlhFilter" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "title": "wlh"     } }
        }
    },
   "explain" : 0
}
```

The results of this query is:

```
   {
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "wlhAggs": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "wellwell",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "else",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "other",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "smth",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "stuff",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      },
      "wlhFilter": {
         "doc_count": 0
      }
   }
}
```

And thats my problem, the wlhFilter should have at least 1 doc count in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of @Byron Voorbach below and his comments this is my solution:

- I have created a separate field which I use synonym analyser on, as
  opposed to having a property field (mainfield.property).
- And most importantly the problem was my synonyms were contracted! I
  had, for example, british,english => uk. Changing that to
  british,english,uk solved my issue and the filter aggregation is
  returning the right number of documents.

Hope this helps someone, or at least point to the right direction.

Edit:
Oh lord praise the documentation! I completely fixed my issue with Filters (S!) aggregation (link [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html)). In filters configuration I specified Match type of query and it worked! Ended up with something like this:

```
"aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "status" :   { "match" : { "cats.saurus" : "monarch"   }},
          "country" : { "match" : { "cats.saurus" : "british" }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice that you figured it out!

Comment: I was posting an update same time..Found even a better solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

I'm short in time, so if needed I can elaborate a bit more at a later time today/tomorrow. But the following should work:

```
DELETE /my_index
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "british,english",
            "queen,monarch"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_synonyms",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST my_index/test/1
{
  "title" : "the british monarch"
}

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "queen"
    }
  }
}

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "queen"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "queen_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": "queen"
        }
      }
    },
    "monarch_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": "monarch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you share the mapping you have defined for your `status.synonym` field?

**EDIT: V2**

The reason why your filter's output is 0, is because a filter in Elasticsearch never goes through an analysis phase. It's meant for exact matches.

The token 'wlh' in your aggregation will not be translated to 'wellwell', meaning that it doesn't occur in the inverted index. This is because, during index time, your 'wlh' is translated into 'wellwell'. 
In order to achieve what you want, you will have to index the data into a separate field and adjust your filter accordingly.

You could try something like:

```
DELETE my_index
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "number_of_replicas": 0, 
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "wlh,wellhead=>wellwell"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "job": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/job/1
{
    "title":"wellhead smth else"
}

PUT my_index/job/2
{
    "title":"wlh other stuff"
}

POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.synonym": {
        "query": "wlh",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "wlhAggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.synonym"
      }
    },
    "wlhFilter": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": "wlh"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "wlhAggs": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "wellwell",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "else",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "other",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "smth",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "stuff",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "wlhFilter": {
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I guess the key bit is the "fielddata": true. If thats the case, Id be interested to know why the synonym field term aggregation works without that setting and filter one doesnt. Need to see how to set field data option using NEST because as far as I can see there is no straight way to set the true flag. Thanks a gain, will come back to you

Comment: If you could show me the mapping for your synonym field, we can see what's going wrong. It looks like the filter aggregation you're using is maybe against an unanalyzed field. If that's true, then ES will not store 'queen' in the inverted index since it wasn't analysed using the synonym analyser.

The reason why i have fielddata=true, is because (without the setting) it’s not possible to aggregate on ‘text’ fields. That’s why it seems that you’re aggregating on a field that doesn’t resolve the synonyms :)

Comment: I have added a section with an example code which you can use to replicate my problem. I should have really started with that to make the question cleaner but not to confuse stuff I wont edit the question part of it. Also, ES version is 2.3.1, I cant replicate your example because text isnt a property/feature until later version. Of course if a version upgrade is needed to make it work then thats not a problem, but Id prefer if this was "last resort".

Comment: Ahh I assumed you were on ES 5, since you had the elasticsearch-5 tag in your question :) I'll have a look at it and come back to you!

Comment: The es-5 tag wasn't intentional,just noticed it now but because it grabbed your attention I don't regret making that mistake! Anyway, thats great but my question still remains - how can I make the filter aggregation detect both documents?For example two documents might be indexed as "wlh" but the filter might be looking for "wellhead" which would produce count of 0, but since they are all synonyms I imagine it should return a count of 2.Or because of the reasons above its impossible? Would this work in ES 5.x? I could write separate match queries for my filter aggregation and get the tot count