# Aggregating synonyms, is it possible with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

A question regarding synonyms:

Is it possible to aggregate data based on synonyms.

For example:
doc_1 - I bought two screens yesterday
doc_2 - My monitor is damaged

Let's say that in such case that 'monitor' and 'screen' are in my synonyms list.

If I'll aggregate by the term 'monitor', will it aggregate doc_1 as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640993/elastic-synonym-usage-in-aggregations